# How can I calculate a time-weighted average in kdb?

Tags: kdb

Calculating weighted averages is easy in kdb thanks to the wavg function. How can I calculate the delay between two consecutive row times and use those values as the weightings parameter to wavg?

Something like:

```
`date`ts xasc select date,ts,mytw:(next ts - ts) wavg mycolumnval from pmd where date=2013.05.22
```

`next` gives the following row column in the query, but I can't figure how to subtract the two ts values and use them in `wavg`.

**UPDATE**
The solution was to use parenthesis: `((next ts) - ts)`. Note that I can't use `deltas[ts]`. This would produce different weights:

```
08:15:19.811    00:00:00.000
08:15:19.811    00:00:00.001
08:15:19.812    00:00:00.014
08:15:19.826    00:00:07.305
08:15:27.131    NULL
```

This is `deltas[ts]`:

```
08:15:19.811    08:15:19.811
08:15:19.811    00:00:00.000
08:15:19.812    00:00:00.001
08:15:19.826    00:00:00.014
08:15:27.131    00:00:07.305
```

Comment: can you give an example of the output you expect? Also in your calc, (next ts - ts) will evaluate right to left, so it will just be next on a list of zeros. You should use deltas instead here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed parenthesis around 'next ts':

```
`date`ts xasc select date,ts,mytw:((next ts) - ts) wavg mycolumnval from pmd where date=2013.05.22
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
`date`ts xasc select date,ts,mytw:deltas[ts] wavg mycolumnval from pmd where date=2013.05.22
```

Comment: There is a problem with this query: the weights are set as (ts - prev ts). I'm updating my question...

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:
`date`ts xasc select date,ts,mytw: (1 _ deltas ts, 0Nv) wavg mycolumnval from pmd where date=2013.05.22. Use 0Np if your ts is datetime

Comment: I'm pretty sure your version doesn't work, I have my queries using the backtick and they work fine. Now if somebody would care to explain the difference (if there is any reason)...

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. the reason is exactly what you have figured out already (next - ts) vs (ts - prev)